# Code skipping the instruction of waiting for multiple events

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, events

I'm coding a program in C++ in *Visual Studio 19* that waits for 640 events to happen (in its case, it's just a array of 640 **HANDLE** where every position needs to move right or left, that is not important).

Well, everyone of those has been initialised as

```
for(i=0; i<640; i++)
    vector[i]=CreateEvent(NULL, true, false, NULL);
```

The issue with this is that the most important thread is the one who waits to all the events to happen, and I do:

```
WaitForMultipleObjects(640, vector, TRUE, INFINITE);
```

And I have the capital problem that  my code just skips that line for some reason. Is there anyone who may tell me what's happening or give me an alternative solution?

Comment: Check the result and if `WAIT_FAILED` call `GetLastError` to get the extended error information.

Comment: I don't see you checking for `NULL` on the `CreateEvent` call.  I don't see you checking the return value (and GetLastError) of `WaitForMultipleObjects` either.  A [mcve] would be strongly preferred as well.  Otherwise, everything is just speculation.

Comment: Also, having a design that explicitly waits for 640 handles at once is a really an unusual design.  It implies an equivalent number of threads (which is a lot for a process) or something that could be consolidated into fewer handles and events.  Can you elaborate on what you are really trying to do?  Maybe there's a better way.

Comment: it's possible that it exists another structure to the shole project but I can't think of anything that runs faster than this. I'm checking things right now, if it does not work, I will use semaphores instead (I'm more used to them). Thx anyways u both  @selbie

Comment: *"but I can't think of anything that runs faster than this"*.  Well, I can. :)

Comment: what did you think of?

Comment: Plenty of suggestions - none of which involve using an event handle. But you'd have to tell me what you are doing to help.  Otherwise, I could give completely invalid if I made invalid assumptions about your design and problem to solve.  I suspect you're just trying to count something or track something across threads and processes.

Comment: Or better yet, pose your design issue around 640 handles as an entirely different question with a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs for [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjects), the maximum number of handles that can be waited on is given by `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS`. A search of the Windows header files shows that it is defined as

```
#define MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS 64     // Maximum number of wait objects
```

in `WinNT.h`.  So you're waiting on too many objects.

Since you want to wait for all of them, you could try breaking your request down into small, manageable sized chunks.

Comment: Thats exactly what happened. Thanks.